# Fastest way to do alternating background color on visible HTML table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a HTML table where I am dynamically adding and hiding rows and I want the current set of visible rows to always show with alternative backcolor for easy reading.

I have the following code that works fine functionally, but is really slow (especially on Internet Explorer browsers)

```
$('table.alternateRow tr:visible').removeClass('odd').filter(':odd').addClass('odd');
```

here is my css:

```
.alternateRow tr {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.alternateRow tr.odd {
    background-color: #DEDEDE;
}
```

Is there any faster solution for this code above that applies to visible rows but doesn't freeze in Internet Explorer.  My table has about 150 - 200 rows visible

Also, (for certain reasons) I want to avoid paging if possible (as a last resort) as it makes the report much harder to read

Comment: on all IEs or just on some versions?

Comment: @@ooo - its actually slow on almost all browsers but its more apparent in IE.  IE8 is tolerable, IE7 and 6 are basically unusable as it just freezes the browser for ages waiting to render.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think the slowest part is selector for `tr:visible`. Add a class for rows `visible`. When you are hiding a row then remove this class. And then try to use `tr.visible` instead of `tr:visible`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code in your question iterates over the table rows twice (once to remove the `odd` class, once to filter the rows), then performs a final pass over the filtered rows to add the `odd` class.

It might be faster to iterate over the rows only once, using [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
$("table.alternateRow tr:visible").each(function(index) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (index & 1) {
        $this.addClass("odd");
    } else {
        $this.removeClass("odd");
    }
});
```

Comment: you say "might be faster". . .wouldn't it, by definition, definitely be faster ?

Comment: @ooo, indeed, it will almost certainly be faster, but that depends on where the bottleneck lies (e.g. if the `:visible` selector is the culprit here, iterating only once will not improve performance very much). I also used weasel wording because I did not benchmark the code in the first place :)

Comment: Can be shortened (code-wise, not time-wise): `$(this).toggleClass("odd", index & 1)`

Comment: @jensgram, yup, I thought about using it, but the current implementation of `toggleClass()` does roughly the same thing (`self[state ? "addClass" : "removeClass"](className);`), so I thought I'd save a function call to gain a little perf. That might be premature optimization however, a benchmark would tell for sure.

Answer (score 2):

With CSS 3 (IE9) you can do the following

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

Although this will not take into account visibility - it does give you a useful selector (odd/even)

*above: Uses CSS doesn't take into account visibility*

**Edit - added clarification incase someone doesn't read all the way to the end**

*below: Uses Jquery **DOES** take into account visibility*

With jQuery (which effectively allows IE 8 and lower to support CSS3) you can put the odd/even part straight into your selector...

```
$('table.alternateRow tr:visible:even').addClass('even');
```

**edit** combined into function

```
function zebra(){
    $('table.alternateRow tr').removeClass('even', 'odd');
    $('table.alternateRow tr:visible:even').addClass('even');
    $('table.alternateRow tr:visible:odd').addClass('odd');
}
```

This is maybe off topic but have you seen the jquery datatables plugin?

http://www.datatables.net/

It handles this sort of stuff seemlessly

Comment: @kissmyface - i didn't put the downvote, but as my questions list, i need a solution for visible rows and that is a requirement

Comment: @ooo This Answer DOES take into account visible rows - did you read all the way to the bottom?

Comment: @kissmyface - the below selector doesn't seem to reset the class on the old rows?

Comment: @ooo You would need to combine it into a function and then call that function each time you modify your table (either by adding rows or showing/hiding). - will edit answer

Comment: @kissmyface - so now i don't think your latest answer would be any faster than the current solution in the question

Answer (score 1):

Your selector seems a bit convoluted. Have a look at what I've done here, it's more concise 
 : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/wTY3p/3/

You basically apply a default and only add the extra class for the even/odd classes.

```
#table tr {
    background:#aa0000;
    color:#fff;
}

#table tr.even {
    background:#00AA00;
    color:#fff;
}

$('#hide').click(function(){
    var rows = [3, 4, 5];
    for (row in rows) {
        $('#table tr:eq(' + row + ')').hide()
    }
    format() 
});

function format() {
    $('#table tr.even').removeClass('even');
    $('#table tr:even').addClass('even');
}
format() 


<button id='hide'>Hide</button>
<table id='table'>
<tbody>
    <tr><td>one</td><td>Two</td></tr>
    <tr><td>one</td><td>Two</td></tr>
    <tr><td>one</td><td>Two</td></tr>
    <tr><td>one</td><td>Two</td></tr>
    <tr><td>one</td><td>Two</td></tr>
    <tr><td>one</td><td>Two</td></tr>
    <tr><td>one</td><td>Two</td></tr>
    <tr><td>one</td><td>Two</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @JohnP - does ":even" selector work on the visible rows or all rows.  I remember originally doing something like this but it seems to get out of whack (consecutive rows had same backcolor) when rows were hidden?

Comment: @ooo Seems to work ok for me. I've created a test script with 200 rows here : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/wTY3p/1/ feel free to play out with it

Comment: @ooo out of the demo, all you actually need is `$('#table tr:even').addClass('even');`. The `format` method is called each time your table has rows hidden/created.

Comment: @JohnP - i think the issue is that i am hiding and creating rows in the middle of an existing table (not just on the end . .)

Comment: @ooo hmmm, I don't think it affects the outcome. Check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/wTY3p/2/ keep in mind that you'll have to reapply the class everytime you change the table

Comment: @JohnP - i agree and understand that i need to reapply the class everytime.  In fact that is my whole point, in one "view" a row can be determine "even" but then if i add a row before it, its no should have the class even.  Where if your code are you removing the fact that row has an "even" class on it ??  I don't see any of the existing fields being "reset" in your answer.

Comment: @ooo whoops, missed the `$('#table tr.even').removeClass('even');` call in `format()`. I've updated. What's curious is that it still worked. Should be ok now

Comment: @JohnP - yeah . . i couldn't figure out why your code on the jsFiddle did seem to work.  maybe just a coincidence :) ? also, why would your latest solution be any faster than my solution

Comment: @ooo for one thing, it doesn't filter twice. Assuming that this selector is what is making IE slow. I tried on IE8, it had no issues.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know jquery so this might be redundant but...

Can't you write your own code that will loop through the rows starting one above (to find out if it is an odd or even row) the highest row made invisible? This means that you won't be looping over all the rows every time a row is hidden or displayed.

Comment: i understand what you are saying but that would still leave the problem on the initial rendering

Answer (score 0):

As you have shown you've defined CSS this way :

```
.alternateRow tr {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.alternateRow tr.odd {
    background-color: #DEDEDE;
}
```

When you are adding the rows dynamically you should check whether there are even or odd number of rows and based on that add a tr of the right class, something like this :

```
$('table.alternateRow').append(function(i,h){
    var tr = '<tr';
    if ( $(this).children('tr').size() % 2 == 0 )
        tr += ' class="odd"';
    tr += '></tr>';
    return tr;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds strange, but it may be **much** faster to change the background colors of the affected rows instead of the classes. IE8 and below are re-rendering the entire table **every** time any of the row's classes change, but do not if only the color or background color changes.

Comment: that is very interesting . . i will try to test this  . .the fact that you say "may be much faster" indicates you are not sure . . if there any reference you have for this info . .also, if i am doing this through javascript on the client side it doesn't appear that the whole table is getting rerendered 200 times if i have a 200 row grid . . how could we tell if this is the case ??

Comment: I don't believe it has much impact because the script re-rendering process starts when the script ends. The problem you described is relevant if there is any JavaScript animation which uses setTimeout or setInterval. But in this case rendering process happens only once.